# Nasty Png in Tbutton on Windows XP SP3 (XP mode Windows 7)

Tags: windows, delphi, image, png, timagelist

I have try my app (dev on Windows 7) on the Windows XP Mode (SP3). And my Tbutton (and other) pictures related to TImageList are very awfull (rounded of black).Do you have an explanation ? Or a solution ?

[image]

Thanks a lot, 
Have a nice day !

EDIT :

@Ken The same EXE, compiled on Windows XP or Windows 7 with D2009 gives me the same result. No transparency on XP Mode SP3 (maybe it is a problem on the virtual machine, but it is strange) and transparency on Windows 7...

@Ken With Delphi 2010 same problem : 
Test file (source+Exe) : http://www.onkeysoft.com/Test.zip

@David :
One with Facebook, and the other don't know why, i have just enter my name and email... I thought i was login but not... (This is the first time I use stackoverflow sorry for problems)

Comment: The explanation might be down to transparency issues, but XP should be able to handle transparent images on buttons OK.

Comment: What version of Delphi? (I'm assuming 2009+ because you mention "png" in your question.) Did you set the proper ColorDepth on the ImageList (cd32Bit, IIRC)?

Comment: Are these really TButtons? I didn't know that they could display glyphs?

Comment: @Ken I'm assuming it's the same exe

Comment: Does XP deal with transparent PNGs?

Comment: @David: I assumed the same exe as well. That doesn't answer either of my questions, though. (There may be differences between 2010 and XE's implementations of TImageList, for instance, or in the .png support.)

Comment: @Ken He must be using a modern Delphi with cd32bit in order for the win7 version to work. I'm guessing it's an XP/transparent PNG mismatch.

Comment: @David: TButton on XP SP2 and up supports images via a TImageList. (I just verified XP SP2 using the PNG images from GlyFX that come with Delphi XE, using XE Pro SKU.) It's an addition to ComCtrls that wasn't previously exposed by TButton because of backwards-compatibility issues; D2009 and up dropped support for the earlier versions of Windows and added the support.

Comment: @Ken Well blow me, and there was me thinking I already knew everything!!  Actually I only ported to D2010 from D6 in the past 6 months so I guess I've not discovered all the new goodies. I'll explore this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @David: Probably a new version, but which one? And I just tested transparent PNGs on a TButton (GlyFX's Vista compatible buttons from one of their libraries from their website) with Delphi XE, and everything looked fine. So the version of Delphi may matter. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Answer :

Windows 7 Pro : No Problem
Windows XP mode (SP3) (Win7Pro) : Problem !

And .... Windows XP SP3 on VirtualBox Emulation : No problem !

So the problem is on the windows XP Mode, and the problem is solved...

(Image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwCtq.png)

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but good formatting is expected of interested users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the option `Enable Runtime Themes` is enabled from Project menu > Options > application.

also try to set the `DrawingSytle` property of the ImageList to `dsTransparent`

Answer (score 0):

By default, windows 7 XP mode emulation runs in 16 bits color mode. Historically, Delphi PNG transparency support hasn't been too happy with color depths other than 32 bits.

Try to run the same application on a real XP machine with the display set to 16 bits, and I'd expect you to encounter the exact same issues.